# Bootstrap compatibility issue on IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-10

I have a bootstrap pop up login page wghich works fine on google chrome but not in IE10 . 
I mean the issue is  when you click close button , it should get invsible by moving top of the page . It works in google chrome but IE10 , no luck

Here is the source html and scripts

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
<link href="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

html side

```
<div id="form-content" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; margin-top: 140px;">

        <form id="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="username">
                    User Name:</label>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtUsername" name="username">*
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="password">
                    Password:</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtPassword" name="password">*
                </div>
                <span id="spanErrorMessage" style="color: Red; display: none;">Invalid username or password.</span>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="btnLogin">
                    Sign Up</button>
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="dialog" title="Message" style="z-index: 9999;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help appreciate.

Thanks ..

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue with the Bootstrap Modal on IE 10: [See Here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3672)

It should work if you remove 'fade' class from the modal element.

**Update**
You can try doing it with jQuery so it will only affect Internet Explorer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) > 8) {
     $("#form-content").removeClass(".fade"); 
   } 
});
```

Comment: it looks worse when i take it off

Comment: can you explain what happens? or post a screenshot?

Comment: I actually want that animation , when i close it should get invisible by moving top as google chrome does . I use this script or not , the result same ..its just get invisible there  is no animation as i expected

Comment: Yes, but like I've said, fade doesn't work in Internet Explorer. That script only removes the fade in internet explorer, so your modal will work great in all browsers, except the fade in internet explorer. Also, you don't need the `in` in the form class

Comment: OK. I will wait for more answer may be there is a way .

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Razvan's solution, if you want to monkey-patch the bootstrap-modal functionality for *all elements* for IE10, you can use something like this:

```
(function($){
    if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) == 10) {
        if (typeof $.fn.modal === 'function') {
            var ogModal = $.fn.modal;
            $.fn.modal = function(options) {
                if (options === 'show') {
                    this.removeClass('fade');
                }
                ogModal.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```